CiviCRM hooks not working in WordPress
So I was trying to use the CiviCRM hooks in my WordPress plugin, and tried multiple variations, but nothing seemed to work.
This is what I was doing in my wordpress plugin:
add_filter( 'civicrm_post', 'my_customhook_civicrm_post', 10, 4  );
function my_customhook_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef) {
    if ($op == "create" && $objectName == "Individual") {
        // DO SOMETHING WHEN INDIVIDUAL CONTACT IS CREATED              
    }
}

But even with all sorts of variations, I could not get it to work.
I found the solution in a random obscure post, and I will answer my own question below with the solution.

I found the answer on this thread: When editing my own profile visible under my contact dashboard, it does not enter CiviCRM "civicrm_post"API hook?
Look at the answer by Hassan Farooq
The solution was that you need to add following before your functions:
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');
So the working code in my wordpress plugin looks like this:
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/pluggable.php');
add_filter( 'civicrm_post', 'my_customhook_civicrm_post', 10, 4  );
function my_customhook_civicrm_post($op, $objectName, $objectId, &$objectRef) {
    if ($op == "create" && $objectName == "Individual") {
        // DO SOMETHING WHEN INDIVIDUAL CONTACT IS CREATED              
    }
}

I have no idea what it does or why it is needed, but is solved my problem!
